# How to find three.js import `.obj` original width and height?

Tags: three.js, objloader

I am the beginner in `Three.js`. I import three.js `.obj` file using the visible 3D object. How to find this `.obj` object original width and height?

Comment: Something like that: `var size = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( _your_obj_ ).getSize();`. But it's better to provide more information in the question.

Comment: Width and height are relative, you cant find it easy.

Answer (score 0):

To make all objects of same size just after import do this,

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
let radius = box.getBoundingSphere().radius;
let scale = 200/radius;
object.scale.multiplyScalar(scale);
```

Comment: Thank you, How to modify the .obj width and height. I tried `object.scale.set(width,height,width)` but object visible enlarge size. How to modified .`obj` object size @answered

Comment: You have to calculate width height with respect of object distance from camera.